# How does one come up with a TOS for a site?

Tags: legal

I don't even know where to start on this other than hiring a lawyer... How does one come up with Terms of Service for a site?

Comment: Truth be told, hire a lawyer to write them is the best way to ensure you are protected in accordance with the latest standard of the law. Every other approach is a band-aid, of unknown validity, and could even be flat wrong or illegal.

Also consider how often active commercial communities do change their TOS.

Comment: First off, there's the obvious. Make sure that people don't break your things, and that they don't break each other.

Comment: Look at similar pages for their TOS. You can inspect these and look what you definitely need. Otherwise, there are Terms of Service Generators out there(Google will help :P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goal of the TOS is to give a **legal framework**, so lawyers are indeed best to author/maintain it.

As a consequence, a TOS is **required** before you launch.

Going further,

- The TOS has a very high chance to be "hard to read" (with legal terms, etc.), and most people actually do not read it, and accept it anyway.
- you probably also want to author (yourself) a **Guidelines & Rules** document, that will explain (in average people terms ;-) the DO and DON'T of your community. This content may point to the TOS.